# My (c++ dynamically generated) page aligns in ie7 but is misaligned in IE8/Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage which includes a Javascript file and a CSS file. The website works fine in IE7 but mis-aligns in IE8, all the buttons are all over the place. It is run through a native C++ application and hence I cannot post a link to it.

HTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8"/>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 15 August 2007)    www.w3.org" />

<!-- specific scripts --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="$SOURCE_DIR$/js/care.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var m_criterionJSON = '$CRITERION$';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var content = '$SOURCE_DIR$';
</script>

<!-- debugging tools -->
<!-- <script type='text/javascript' src='https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js'></script> -->

<!-- css files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$SOURCE_DIR$/css/care.css" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:load();if (_loadTimer) _loadTimer.Stop();">
</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT SAMPLE FOR THE DIALOG:

```
create: function createDialog(person) {
    this.width = Math.round(Care.body.width() * .7);    
    this.container = $(document.createElement("div"));
    this.container.addClass("dialog-container");

    this.dialog  = $(document.createElement("div"));
    this.dialog.addClass("dialog");

    var html = '<table class="dialog-table">';
    html += this.createTitle();
    html += this.createSelect();
    html += this.createContent(person);
    html += '</table>';
    this.dialog.append(html);

    this.select = $($(this.dialog.children()[0].rows[1].cells[0]).children()[1]);
    this.content = $(this.dialog.children()[0].rows[2].cells[0]);
    this.table = $($(this.content.children()[0]).children()[0]);
    this.createButtons();

    this.container.append(this.dialog);
```

CSS SNIPET:

```
.dialog-container {top:0px; z-index:101; position:absolute; height:100%; text-align:center; }
.dialog-table {position:relative; padding:0px; margin: 0px; border:0px;}
```

[image: Image for the Hover]
[image: Image for the Dialog]

[image: Fixed]

[image: Fixed]

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Well, for starters, there *aren't any* buttons.  There's no content in the `body` at all.  Can you post code that actually reproduces the issue for us?

Comment: can you post screenshots perhaps? a visual representation would be immensely helpful

Comment: Hello, I have added Screenshot, and CSS and Javascript hopefully it is better now. The dialog in IE7 is much bigger in size almost full screen.

Comment: The hover in IE7 appears at the end of the row not the beginning.

Comment: So my crystal ball tells me that the first screenshot is from IE4, the second from Lynx, the third from blackberry 12 browser, and the last one from Opera 17. Is my crystal ball correct? If not, I'll try the tea leaf. Nevertheless, labeling your images clearly **is not** important at all; the important thing is, according to my crystal ball, you don't have an IE 7 screenshot.

Comment: sorry for that the first two are the IE8 screen shots and the 3 and 4th one are from IE7. I did write description in my question I don't know why its not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this from top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

it causes your UAs to go in quirk mode in older browsers.

Comment: in that case you have to narrow down your problem to the specifics. post an image of how it is "right" in IE7 and "miss-aligned" in IE8/Chrome so we can compare the two. Also post the ONLY revealant markup and css. Your current HTML tells us nothing

Comment: The HTML file actually just calls the Javascript file which dynamically creates the HTML. The CSS is the classes that I currently use. I will post more screen shots.

Comment: I have put up screen shots of how it looks in IE7